# asymptotic behavior of $N_{\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}/\mathbb{Q}}(1-\alpha ^n)$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

We have an algebraic complex number  $\alpha$  such that $|\alpha|=1$ and it is not a root of unity, We also know that $ \alpha \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ (ring of integers).
I need to study the behavoir of $N_{\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}/\mathbb{Q}}(1-\alpha ^n)$ when $n\rightarrow \infty $.
Could someone give me a bibliographic reference?